# "Cannot allocate memory" error for psycopg2 and libgcrypt.so on Debian 6, 64bit

Tags: python, memory-management, debian, 32bit-64bit, psycopg2

I am having a weird production specific error related to Python psycopg2 postgresql driver and libgcrypt module.

I was running Debian 6, 32bit to host my application with uWSGI and Nginx. I decided to switch to 64bit with fresh install. Everything seemed fine except I am getting below Python traceback for every request in the uwsgi.log:

```
  File ".../python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 272, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File ".../python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 169, in get_response
    response = self.handle_uncaught_exception(request, resolver, sys.exc_info())
  File ".../python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 203, in handle_uncaught_exception
    return debug.technical_500_response(request, *exc_info)
  File ".../python2.7/site-packages/django/views/debug.py", line 59, in technical_500_response
    html = reporter.get_traceback_html()
and so on...
```

So, I went to django/core/handlers/base.py (Django version 1.3.1) line 166 which seems the last exception handler that holds everything really exceptional. I replaced it with:

```
except Exception, why:
```

and write the "why" to a text file. The exception is exactly that:

```
Error loading psycopg2 module: libgcrypt.so.11: failed to map segment from shared object: Cannot allocate memory
```

I read almost every similar bug / issue / blogpost and could only find that one that believe not exactly same issue but quite similar:
http://www.johngirvin.com/archives/dovecot-error-127-after-upgrading-to-debian-squeeze.html

I did try with:

- Django==1.3.1
- Django==1.3
- psycopg2==2.4.2
- psycopg2==2.4.1

also rebooted which gave no result. I have postgresql-8.4, libgcrypt11 and libgcrypt11-dev installed on the system. PostgreSQL has no model except a fresh ./manage.py syncdb with Django default ones. There is more than half of the memory is just empty.

And... I also tried to run ./manage.py runserver on production which works perfectly fine. The VPS is on Linode, so I don't think there is any hardware problem.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I think I should ask this question to serverfault.com. Kind of late perhaps.. Does anyone know if I can move it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is perhaps not about Python, Django, PostgreSQL, psycopg2 nor libsomething.so.

Check if you have option like [--limit-as](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Options.html#limit-as) in your uWSGI configuration. On 64bit systems address space can be twice big. 512 or 1024 should do the job so raise it as necessary.